# Ruby on Rails - How to pass variable inside %w{}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to pass a variable inside `%w{}` just like this:

```
@my_text = "Hello rails"
%w{@my_text}
```

This code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby **%w** will not allow interpolation, you should be using **%W** like below,

```
@my_text = 'Hello rails'
%W{#{@my_text}}
# => ["Hello rails"]
```

Comment: But it does not convert string into array.